# Pytorch advanced indexing with list of lists as indices

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

Here is some python code to reproduce my issue:

```py
import torch

n, m = 9, 4

x = torch.arange(0, n * m).reshape(n, m)
print(x.shape)
print(x)
# torch.Size([9, 4])
# tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#         [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14, 15],
#         [16, 17, 18, 19],
#         [20, 21, 22, 23],
#         [24, 25, 26, 27],
#         [28, 29, 30, 31],
#         [32, 33, 34, 35]])

list_of_indices = [
    [],
    [2, 3],
    [1],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [],
    [0, 3],
]
print(list_of_indices)

for i, indices in enumerate(list_of_indices):
    x[i, indices] = -1

print(x)
# tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5, -1, -1],
#         [ 8, -1, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14, 15],
#         [16, 17, 18, 19],
#         [20, 21, 22, 23],
#         [-1, -1, -1, -1],
#         [28, 29, 30, 31],
#         [-1, 33, 34, -1]])
```

I have a list of list of indices. I want to set the indices in `x` to a specific value (here `-1`) using the indices in `list_of_indices`. In this list, each sublist correspond to a row of `x`, containing the indices to set to `-1` for this row. This can be easily done using a for-loop, but I feel like pytorch would allow to do that much more efficiently.

I tried the following:

```py
x[torch.arange(len(list_of_indices)), list_of_indices] = -1
```

but it resulted in

```py
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing tensors could not be broadcast together with shapes [9], [9, 0]
```

I tried to find people having the same problem, but the number of questions about indexing tensors is so large that I might have missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this in-place you can simply flatten `x`. You should *ravel* the indices such that they can index `x` when flattened. First, gather the indices, then index `x.flatten()` (fyi. **not** a copy).

```
indices = torch.tensor([i*m+j for i,r in enumerate(list_of_indices) for j in r])
> tensor([ 6,  7,  9, 24, 25, 26, 27, 32, 35])

x.flatten()[indices] = -1
> tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
          [ 4,  5, -1, -1],
          [ 8, -1, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14, 15],
          [16, 17, 18, 19],
          [20, 21, 22, 23],
          [-1, -1, -1, -1],
          [28, 29, 30, 31],
          [-1, 33, 34, -1]])
```

You can also use [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html), but in that case it is slightly longer to write:

```
x.flatten().scatter_(0,indices,value=-1).view_as(x)
```

Comment: Your solution seems quite faster than the other one! For my specific case (n*m~250*40), the one using `scatter_` is the fastest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `list_of_indices` is a ragged `list` (i.e. it contains empty nested `[]`s and `list`s of different `len`gths), so if we include a function that returns a `tensor` the same `shape` as `x` where `1`s are the `indices` from `list_of_indices` (and `0`s are the indices not in `list_of_indices`), then we can just input that into `torch.where` indexing `x`:

```
def get_indices_from_list(list_of_indices):
    def fill_list(f):
        _f = torch.zeros(4).long(); _f[f] = 1
        return _f
    return torch.stack([fill_list(i) for i in list_of_indices])

x[torch.where(get_indices_from_list(list_of_indices) == 1)] = -1
print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5, -1, -1],
        [ 8, -1, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [-1, -1, -1, -1],
        [28, 29, 30, 31],
        [-1, 33, 34, -1]])
```

Comment: I was hoping for a direct method without having to fill the list with zeros, but I guess that's not possible. Thank you!